# Shopware 6.5 : Using category tree in the customfields

Tags: plugins, shopware, shopware6

I am developing a plugin in Shopware 6.5 that enables the store owner to choose categories on the customer edit screen. I have included a `CustomFieldTypes::ENTITY` custom field in the customer entity and utilized `'componentName' => 'sw-entity-multi-id-select'` to show the multi-select in the customer edit. However, I want to display the category tree instead of the multi-select. How can I accomplish this?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After conducting extensive research and discussions, I have successfully created a custom field component that can be utilized for category trees throughout the admin.
If anyone is interested in learning more about this, please don't hesitate to reach out to [us](https://www.2hatslogic.com/).

Comment: Please provide the rough details here, otherwise this answer is not considered helpful (even I am happy, that you did find a solution)